# Text overflow inside a column. How force the text to always expand horizontally and be inline with the column width

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, overflow

I created a file input. After selecting a file, its name is displayed in a column.

When the file name is extremely long, it expands vertically. There is a way to force the text to always expand horizontally, but if you fill in the column width, the name does not appear complete (example: asdasdasdasdasd .... (that is, the three points are added)

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqbqdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div class="card bg-light mb-3" style="width:40%; height:500px; overflow-y:scroll">
    <div class="card-header">Attachment</div>
    <div class="card-body att">
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
        <div *ngFor="let url of items">
            <div class="row attach">
                <div class="col">
                    {{url.fileType}}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{url.filename}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgtBe.png)

**WHAT I tried**

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

expands the text horizontally, but the text is not in line with the extension or with the column :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: It does not respect the width of the column and completely fills the row :( I intend the text to leave some margin right at the end of the row

Comment: add screenshot what you want

Comment: Solved ! I add a col and perfect ! Thank you !